# Echo parameters to a log file

Tags: batch-file

I need to add logging to a batch file to know what parameters were passed to it.
So if the batch file is run.bat, I have tried adding the line

```
ECHO %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 >> run.log
```

Which just echoes the parameters and the string `>> run.log`.

Comment: Are you sure `run.log` isn't getting created?  Do you have `@ECHO OFF` on your first line?  What parameters are being passed in to cause it to fail?  Post the rest of your code; the code you've supplied writes out to `run.log` just fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have an unclosed quote somewhere in your parameter list (e.g. `foo.cmd "bar` would cause that behaviour). You can likely solve this by putting the redirection in front of the `echo` (yes, this works):

```
>> run.log echo %*
```